# HTML/ CSS: placing section on right side of the screen using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I wonder how I can place the `section class="teacher__section` on the right side of the screen using flexbox. Not by float. I have written "justify-content: flex-end;", width 80% also 100% but it doesnt seem to be placing on right side.

I mean I have on the picture below succeeded placing the section on the right side, but the problem now is the left side where I want to get rid of the extra white box and the extra box-shadow. I want it to go around the image just like in
`<section class="explore__section">` where I have the box-shadow go around the image. Source code is under below the image.

[image]

Source code:

```css
.explore__container {
  margin: 5% 0 2% 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10rem;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0rem 2rem 2rem 0;
}

.forkids__info {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-right: -20%;
}

.forkids__img {
  background-image: url(/img/kids-science.jpeg);
  flex-basis: 50%;

  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 0rem 2rem 2rem 0;
}

.teacher__section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0rem 2rem 2rem 0;
}

.teacher__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
}

.teacher__info {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-left: -20%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.teacher__img {
  background-image: url(/img/teacher-science.jpg);
  flex-basis: 50%;

  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 0 100%);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="explore__section">

        <div class="explore__container">
            <div class="forkids__info"> some text</div>
            <div class="forkids__img"></div>

        </div>
        
     </section>

     <section class="teacher__section">
        <div class="teacher__container">
            <div class="teacher__img"></div>
            <div class="teacher__info">some text</div>
            

        </div>
     </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution, Hope this will help

```
<section class="explore__section">
  <div class="explore__container">
    <div class="forkids__info"> some text</div>
    <div class="forkids__img"></div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <section class="teacher__section">
    <div class="teacher__container">
      <div class="teacher__img"></div>
      <div class="teacher__info">some text</div>
    </div>
  </section>

<style>
.explore__container {
  margin: 5% 0 2% 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10rem;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0rem 2rem 2rem 0;
}

.forkids__info {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-right: -20%;
}

.forkids__img {
  background-image: url(/img/kids-science.jpeg);
  flex-basis: 50%;

  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 0rem 2rem 2rem 0;
}

.teacher__section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  border-radius: 0rem 2rem 2rem 0;
}

.teacher__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10rem;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
}

.teacher__info {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-left: -20%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.teacher__img {
  background-image: url(/img/teacher-science.jpg);
  flex-basis: 50%;

  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 0 100%);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
}
</style>
```